# I am not able to understand input values for swapExactTokensForTokens

Tags: bsc

I am trying to execute the function swapExactTokensForTokens on testnet bsc user interface for the router smart contract of bsc tesnet : 0x9a489505a00cE272eAa5e07Dba6491314CaE3796

when I fill the first input field with 0.01 I dont receive 0.01 tbnb worth of the any other token, I only receive a very small amount, here is an example of a transaction I made :
[image: small amounts received but my wallet lost O.01 tbnb]

I think the issue is related to some mistake I am making in the input fields : [image]

can some one please tell me what should I write in each input field be cause I am lost at this point, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **amountIn**: The amount of input tokens to send for swap
- **amountOutMin**: The minimum amount of output tokens that must be received; use [getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path)](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L427C14-L427C65) to determine this
- **path**: Pools for each consecutive pair of addresses must exist and have liquidity
- **to**: Address of who you're sending the tokens to

*Amounts are in Wei = (amount ETH - or BNB in your case) x (10^18)*

Comment: thanks a lot! I have two additional question to be able to fully understand : 
1) what about the first input field named like the function : "swapExactTokensForTokens"?
2) what if I want to swap "cake" against "XYZ" token (with existing pool) I will just need to add the two tokens adresses in the path and insert the  amount of cake x10^18  in amountIn ?

Comment: Not sure about first field; standard Router code doesn't have that first field for swapExactTokensForTokens

Comment: thanks a lot, I am still not able to understand how to go back from cake to any other token, I did the first transaction (tBNB ==> cake) and now I just want to go back but nothing is working, I flip the adresses in the path flip the value amoutIn and amountOut, nothing is working ... thank's a lot for the help.